During installation of Sitecore 10.3 getting database related error
During the installation of Sitecore 10.3 getting database related error like

Connection was sussesfully established , but error occured during
login process, The Certificate chain issued by authority not trusted.



Sitecore’s installer generates a self-signed certificate in order to secure your instance. SQL uses an encrypted connection with Sitecore, and you are using a self-signed certificate, which is not trusted, hence, the error.
You’ll need to modify two files, xconnect-xp0.json and sitecore-xp0.json. Search for "Type": "InvokeSqlcmd" in both, and wherever you find a match, add "TrustServerCertificate": true to its "Params" property. In total, there will 4 or 5 matches inside xconnect-xp0.json and 1 in sitecore-xp0.json where you’ll need to make this change.
Reference: How to Resolve 'Certificate Chain Was Issued by an Authority That is Not Trusted' 
Hope it helps!

thnx issue resolved

There are two files that you’ll need to modify, xconnect-xp0.json and sitecore-xp0.json. Search for "Type": "InvokeSqlcmd" in both, and wherever you find a match, add "TrustServerCertificate": true to its "Params" property. In total, there will 4 or 5 matches inside xconnect-xp0.json and 1 in sitecore-xp0.json where you’ll need to make this change.

thnx issue resolved

Sitecore installation using encrypted connection to MS SQL Server, that utilizes self-signed certificate which is not trusted in your case, hence the issue is occuring.
In order to resolve this issue, search for the "Type": "InvokeSqlcmd" on the folder where XConnect Scripts are located. It will be there on 5 places inside xconnect-xp0.json file and one place inside sitecore-XP0.json file. Inside each of these commands , add "TrustServerCertificate": true in the params property as shown below.

Once above changes are done, you can delete the current Sitecore instance and restart the installation again.
Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you face any issues.

thnx issue resolved
